# Popup div when window close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a POPUP div when user clicks on close window button.

At the moment i have this code:

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function PopIt() { 
    $("a#trigger").trigger('click');
    window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt;
    return "Would you like to join our mailing list for other offers?"; 
}

function UnPopIt()  { /* nothing to return */ } 

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = PopIt;

    $("a#trigger").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'showCloseButton': false
    });

    $("a[id!=trigger]").click(function(){ window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt; });
});
```

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <a id="trigger" href="#popup">&nbsp;</a>
    <div id="popup" style="width: 250px; height: 400px;">
        <p>This would be an aweber form.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works, but not really the way I need. It popups the standard browser box with two buttons, stay or leave. I want to popup the div with id POPUP.

Please, can some one help me to fix my code?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/szetavvy/1/)

Thank you!

Comment: JSFiddle would be nice

Comment: Here is FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/szetavvy/1/

Comment: Thats what onbeforeunload does.  You don't get to substitute the behavior, just the text in the dialog

Comment: @Andrei Ok I see what you mean. You can't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Comment: it looks like I must give up?

Comment: Yeah, just make a nice unobtrusive newsletter subscription box, that doesn't block the user